# PyQt5 seg fault when importing QQuickImageProvider

Tags: pyqt5, segmentation-fault, python-import

i've encountered a very weird behavior which led to a seg fault when working on my app.
can someone please explain why it crashes ?

system:

- ubuntu 18.04
- PyQt 5.9.2
- python 3.6

conditions:

- have a QApplication based class
- create QQmlApplicationEngine (even if its not used)
- import- from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickImageProvider (even if its not used)
- have a signal/slot that send/recieve a list type and send a [None]
- emit the signal only after the engine is instantiated

** it doesnt matter if the slot has a @pyqtslot decorator or not

** if i change the signal signature to object instead of list everything is fine

** if you remove even one of the conditions you wont get the seg fault.

example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickImageProvider # if you comment out it wont crash

APP = None

class SomeCrashingClass(QObject):
    sig = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.sig.connect(self.my_func)
        self.sig.emit([None]) # if you send a [] it wont crash

    def my_func(self):
        print(f"-------------everything is fineeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee-----------------")

class CrashingApp(QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CrashingApp, self).__init__(sys.argv)
        self._engine = QQmlApplicationEngine() # if you comment out it wont crash
        bla = SomeCrashingClass()

    def run(self):
        print(f"---------------------running the app ------------------")
        exit_status = self.exec_()
        print(f"----------exit status {exit_status}")


def run():
    global APP
    APP = CrashingApp()
    sys.exit(APP.run())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

---

EDIT:

- changing sig = pyqtSignal(object) solves the issue

Comment: Have you tried to run the program in a terminal or prompt to see the full traceback of the crash?

Comment: Use `sig = pyqtSignal(object)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks, already tried that and indeed it solves the issue, im more curious about the cause tho

Comment: It seems to be a bug in PyQt. It should be possible to serialise any type that can be converted to a `QVariant` - including `None`. It works as expected in the opposite direction (i.e. sending `[QVariant()]` or `[QVariant(None)]` is received as `[None]`). But whatever the exact behaviour is intended to be, it obviously shouldn't ever result in a core dump, no matter how the API is (ab)used. I suggest you report it on the [pyqt mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

Comment: @ekhumoro i sure will, btw does anyone has access and can see if this happens for a higher PyQt verison ? i cant update for now

Comment: Yes, I already tested it with pyqt-5.15.6 and pyqt-6.2.3. The problems are mostly the same, and the same work-arounds fix them. I only tested on arch-linux, though (using the official packages).